# Python regex loop skipping every third item

Tags: python, regex, matching

I'm doing a tokenizer and I want to separate strings like "word-bound-with-hyphen" into "word xxsep bound xxsep with xxsep hyphen".

I tried this:

```
import re

s = "words-bound-with-hyphen"
reg_m = re.compile("[\w\d]+-[\w\d]+")
reg = re.compile("([\w\d]+)-([\w\d]+)")
while(reg_m.match(s)):
    s = reg.sub(r"\1 xxsep \2", s)
print(s) #prints "words xxsep bound-with xxsep hyphen"
```

But this leaves every third hyphen-bound word.

Comment: if you are not limited to regex solutions, I'd suggest
`for _ in range(s.count('-')):
    s = reg.sub(r"\1 xxsep \2", s)`

Comment: Try going the other way around, use the hyphens as capturing groups.

Comment: If you think an answer fits your question, please use the tick mark to mark it.

Comment: Why not use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Search for [`\b-\b` and replace with  `xxsep`](https://regex101.com/r/Ezyglv/2).

Answer (score 2):

You could just replace the hyphens with a regex:

```
In [4]: re.sub("-", " xxsep ", "word-bound-with-hyphen")
Out[4]: 'word xxsep bound xxsep with xxsep hyphen'
```

or with string substitution:

```
In [7]: "word-bound-with-hyphen".replace("-", " xxsep ")
Out[7]: 'word xxsep bound xxsep with xxsep hyphen'
```

The reason your current approach doesn't work is that `re.sub()` [returns **non-overlapping** groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) whereas `word-bound` overlaps with `bound-with` overlaps with `with-hyphen`.

Comment: This is the best solution, if you also want hyphens replaced that are for example at the end or beginning of the string, or between spaces.

Comment: Thanks! 

I used an alteration to ensure that hyphens used in ordinary text stays, solution now looks like this:

```s = re.sub("[^\s]-[^\s]", " xxsep ", s)```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
s = "words-bound-with-hyphen"
re.sub('-',' xxsep ',s)
```

or without using regular expressions

```
" xxsep ".join(x.split('-'))
```

here, the list will be separated taking - as delimiter and then joined using "xxsep"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to just replace all hyphens but only those that are preceded and followed by certain characters than use regex lookbacks and lookaheads.

```
import re
s = "words-bound-with-hyphen"
re.sub('(?<=[\w\d])-(?=[\w\d])',' xxsep ', s)
# result: 'words xxsep bound xxsep with xxsep hyphen'
```